# Angular-material

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5, angular-material

проблема с иконками в Angular-material. Не то что проект не отображает иконки, даже сайт https://material.angular.io/ не отображает иконок, как я понял проблема в браузере, пробовал переустановить браузер а так же запускать на других браузерах, результат тот же: отображается только название иконок, хотя на телефоне всё нормально

вот скрины:

`<mat-icon matBadge="{{service.cart.length}}">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
это скрин с телефона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Vahan jan могу чем то помочь? Или проблема уже решена?